# Extract P-Values from Dunnett Test into a Table by Variable

Tags: r, extract

I have a list of 25 columns that I am testing to by group (4 levels) through a Dunnett test. I was able to use the `sapply` function to get the Dunnett to work for all the columns by group and am having some trouble pulling the p-values into a table. Below is an example of what I am trying to do using the iris dataset.

```
iris <- iris

iris$group <- ifelse(iris$Species =='setosa', 1,
               ifelse(iris$Species =='versicolor', 2,
               ifelse(iris$Species =='virginica', 3,
               0)))

iris$group <- as.factor(iris$group)
summary(glht(aov(Sepal.Length ~ group, iris), linfct=mcp(group="Dunnett" )))
test

iris$Species

dunnet_model_iris <- sapply(iris[-c(5,6)], function(y, f) summary(glht(aov(y ~ f, iris), linfct=mcp(f="Dunnett"))), f = iris$Species)

names(dunnet_model_iris[[10]]$pvalues)

p_value <- dunnet_model[[10]]$pvalues
p_value
```

I am able to get the p-values for each column through dunnet_model[[10]]$pvalues (with each column being 10 rows apart (for example: the second column would be dunnet_model[[20]]$pvalues). In total, my data set has 25 columns so I would pull from 10-250. I would like to create a table like this:

```
                2-1       3-1
Sepal.Length  1.44E-15  2.22E-16
Sepal.Width   1.44E-15  2.22E-16
Petal.Length  1.44E-15  2.22E-16
```

**Question: How do I pull out all the Dunnett Comparison P-values for each column into a single table?**

I am having some trouble searching for the answer. If anyone has some suggestions that would be greatly appreciated. I am not expecting any code, just some ideas to help shine some light on my situation.

Comment: You may be having difficulty in searching if you have been using that spelling of "Dunnett". You should correct all the instances in your title and question body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to extract the `test$pvalues` after keeping the model in the `list` with `lapply`

```
library(multcomp)
dunnet_model_iris <- lapply(iris[-c(5,6)], function(y, f) 
      summary(glht(aov(y ~ f, iris), linfct=mcp(f="Dunnett"))), f = iris$Species)
t(sapply(dunnet_model_iris, function(x) x$test$pvalues))
#                      [,1]         [,2]
#Sepal.Length  1.443290e-15 2.220446e-16
#Sepal.Width   5.551115e-16 9.074667e-10
#Petal.Length  1.110223e-16 2.220446e-16
#Petal.Width  -2.220446e-16 1.110223e-16
```

---

Or using the OP's method of creating the 'dunnet_model_iris'

```
t(sapply(dunnet_model_iris["test",], `[[`, "pvalues"))
```